# Getting Specific Value from Dmidecode Output with Bash Script

Tags: bash, awk

Below is a section from the dmidecode output. There is a part of this section that I want to break down. I want to get the 4 bytes after pattern **01 85 30**. And I want to change the byte order. Then I will compare with the hex strings I have.

```bash
....... 
Handle 0x0027, DMI type 219, 106 bytes
OEM-specific Type
        Header and Data:
                DB 6A 27 00 01 04 01 45 02 00 90 06 *01 85 30* 20
                00 00 00 00 40 00 00 03 1F 24 02 C9 02 60 44 02
                FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
                FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 03 00 00 00 80 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 04 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
                FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
.......
```

Expected output : 00000020

I prepared a bash script and it works, is there a better way?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

id_array=("00000020", "00000040")
unique_id=$(dmidecode -t 219 | grep "01 85 30" -A 1 | xargs | cut -c 46-56 | tr -d '[:space:]' | grep -o .. | tac | paste -sd ''  -)
if [[ " ${id_array[*]} " == *"$unique_id"* ]];
then
  echo "1"
else
  echo "0"
fi
```

Comment: Think about using `lshw` instead, which has both XML and JSON output formats so you can retrieve specific content with `jq`, `xmlstarlet`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following, let `command` give output

```
Handle 0x0027, DMI type 219, 106 bytes
OEM-specific Type
        Header and Data:
                DB 6A 27 00 01 04 01 45 02 00 90 06 01 85 30 20
                00 00 00 00 40 00 00 03 1F 24 02 C9 02 60 44 02
                FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
                FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 03 00 00 00 80 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 04 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
                FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
.......
```

then

```
command | awk 'BEGIN{RS="01[[:space:]]85[[:space:]]30"}NR>1{print $4 $3 $2 $1}'
```

gives output

```
00000020
```

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that row separator (`RS`) is given sequence, I use `[[:space:]]` rather than just space to allow situations when sequence does go through multiple lines, then for each line beyond 1st I print 4th field concatenated with 3rd field with 2nd field with 1st field.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

`Awk` solution allowing for line breaks that might disrupt the search pattern and the byte values being sought.

I've used two short awk procedures pipped together. The first formats the data such that the search pattern and following bytes are always separated by a single space, without line breaks, or any tabs or runs of spaces.

The second procedure divides the data at the now clean pattern set and extracts the first four bytes of the second record (the part immediately following the pattern), and prints them in reverse order.

**whole procedure** (`file` contains the original data)

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "; OFS=" "} {gsub(FS," ",$0); $1=$1; print$0}' file | awk -v pattern="01 85 30" 'BEGIN{RS=pattern} NR==2{print $4" "$3" "$2" "$1}'
```

**output**

```
00 00 00 20
```

**Explanation of parts**

**part 1**

takes the data file `file` and re-formats to produce an output that contains each white-space separated 'word' of the input file but now separated by a single space.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "; OFS=" "} {gsub(FS," ",$0); $1=$1; print$0}' file |
```

This is achieved by setting both the output record separator `ORS` and output field separator `OFS` to a single space in the `BEGIN` block. The main block then substitutes the default input field separator`FS` (white space of any length) for a single space character in each record, using `gsub(FS," ",$0);`. The record (line) is then printed (`print $0`) after forcing awk to reevaluate it (using `$1=$1`) to prevent the line being passed as it was received.

The **output** of the first part is:

```
Handle 0x0027, DMI type 219, 106 bytes OEM-specific Type Header and Data: DB 6A 27 00 01 04 01 45 02 00 90 06 01 85 30 20 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 03 1F 24 02 C9 02 60 44 02 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 03 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
```

and is piped directly to the second awk procedure

**part 2**

```
| awk -v pattern="01 85 30" 'BEGIN{RS=pattern} NR==2{print $4" "$3" "$2" "$1}'
```

uses the variable flag `v` to pass the search pattern into the awk procedure `-v pattern="01 85 30"` allowing the combined procedure to be called repeatedly from a shell command if many patterns are to be processed (by setting the pattern to a shell variable and using the variable name in place of the string "01 85 30").

A `BEGIN` block sets the record separator to be the passed pattern (`RS=pattern`) so that subsequent blocks will examine chunks of the file either side of the pattern as individual records.

Since the required data immediately follows the pattern we are only interested in the second record so the main awk block filters for record 2 (`NR==2`), printing the first four fields in reverse order, separated by single spaces,  with `print $4" "$3" "$2" "$1`